# Electric current and motion of electrons

Tags: electric-current, acoustics, velocity, collision

When a battery provides energy to an electric circuit, the electrons get aligned so as to transfer energy from the negative terminal to the positive terminal. The drift velocity of the electrons in a conductor where no energy is supplied is $0$ because the displacement of the electrons remains $0$. Once energy is supplied, for the transfer, the electrons gain a drift velocity $(\approx 0.1cm/s)$.

My question here is, why the electrons gain the drift velocity. I'll give an analogy, let's take sound waves into consideration. Sound gets conveyed through vibrations of the particles about their mean positions, so ideally the electrons need not move at all, they can just collide and oscillate about their mean positions. Why do they flow? Interelectronic repulsions should not allow movement of charge at all right?

Please help me with the above conceptual doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free electrons in a metal do not have any "mean position". The positive ions form a lattice and indeed they vibrate around their equilibrium positions (motion which is part of the thermal energy of the crystal). The free electrons (or conduction electrons) move through the metal with velocities of the order $10^5$ m/s in the absence of any external field. This motion does not result in charge transport because the average momentum is zero (same as the average momentum of a gas is zero in the CoM frame).   But this motion contributes to the thermal energy of the metal (even though is a relative small contribution). The interaction between the free electrons is negligible (or negected in most models). In the presence of an external electric field the already present thermal velocity of each electron gains a small component in the direction of the field. This does not average to zero as all electrons gain the velocity (drift velocity) in the same direction. And so a net charge transport results.
The interaction between the conduction electrons is negligible for usual electric conduction. The electrons do not gain the drift velocity because they are "pushed" by other conduction electrons so the analogy with a wave, where the interaction propagates by interaction between neighbouring particles, each electron pushing the next one along the wire, is not a good one. Even if it is used by some authors of introductory or popular science texts.

Answer (score 1):

How about if instead of sound, you're powering your equipment with a water turbine.  There, the water does flow in a single direction.  It's just a different setup.

You're correct, the flow itself is not necessary to transfer power.  If instead of a battery we use an AC generator to power the circuit, then the long-term drift of the charges is zero.  The charges move back and forth with a net velocity of zero, but power is still transferred through the circuit.

In a battery, one terminal is trying to produce extra electrons and the other terminal is trying to consume electrons.  When the circuit connects them, they flow through the wire to allow these reactions to proceed.